# Upgrade script looking for a false table?

Tags: database, eav, upgrade-script

I have a custom module that I need to update adding a couple of columns in one of the tables. The task is very easy but for some reason Magento is adding a prefix on my table name. Let me show you.

My upgrade script is as follows:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
$installer->getTable('invent_feedbanners/imagen'), 'inicia', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, array(
    ), 'Inicia');

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
$installer->getTable('invent_feedbanners/imagen'), 'termina', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, array(
    ), 'Termina');
$installer->endSetup();
```

When the upgrade runs Magento reports an error like this:
- SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '255.invent_feedbanners_imagen' doesn't exist"

The name of the table is invent_feedbanners_imagen. Where does the 255 name comes from??. My installation doesnt have any prefix.

This has been breaking my head for the last 5 hours. I'm stuck on this. If somebody could help me I will appreciate it alot.

Kind Regards!

Comment: can you paste the `config.xml` of your module?

Comment: I think '255' is your magento DB name!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue why you do this, but the method `addColumn` accepts other parameters:

```
public function addColumn($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $schemaName = null);
```

Therefore it should be:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('invent_feedbanners/imagen'),
    'termina',
    array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
        'comment' => 'Termina'
    ),
);
```